# How to store the map-reducede out-put in different node ???

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I want to store catagorized data in different node in hadoop .

ex:

```
Node - 1 >> Animal.txt
Node - 2 >> Sports.txt
Node - 3 >> Life.txt
.
.
.
Node - n >> nnnnn.txt
```

Is there a way to do that.

**Sorry if my description is weak.

Comment: What's the purpose of storing data on a particular node. Maybe an alternate solution can be thought.

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible to partition your data so that each subset (animals, sports, life) is local to the same node, although you can't reliably choose the identity of the physical node they are stored on.

As long as you can programatically identify each record as being a part of a set (animal, sports, life, etc in your case) then you can implement your own [Partitioner](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/Partitioner.html).  This is similar to implementing a hash function where all keys with the same hash code will be reduced by the same reducer.

[Raw Input] -> [Identity Mapper] -> [Your custom Partitioner] -> [Identity Reducer]

As other users have mentioned, HDFS will replicate the output data to other nodes by default.  So you will have to disable replication in this case if you want to guarantee data locality.  Of course this comes at the cost of fault tolerance.

Answer (score 0):

By storing files on specific nodes you are defeating the point of HDFS - it has redundant copies. I don't think you HAVE to use HDFS though. You might create a reduce job which writes to the local file system, but I don't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

The underlying data storage facility (HDFS) hides completely where the data is actually stored. So knowing this is for your application a "you shouldn't need to know this".

On the other hand i'm quite curious why you want to control this?